These two Qatar flights with slightly different times and different flight number must actually be the same flight, right?
I am getting two apparently different Qatar flights from Doha to Chennai, QR4788 and Q3528, with very close but ever so slightly timings. Their timing differs by only 5-10 minutes.
Since I find it very unlikely that Qatar would operate two flights on the same route almost simultaneously, I assume these two actually refer to the same airplane? What is going on here? Why are they showing up as two different flights?



QR4788 generally departs 0200 and arrives 0900 while QR 528 departs 1950 and arrives 0250 (next day). Maybe on that particular day one of the flights has been rescheduled?

Two or more flights by the same company between the same set of airports does happen. If the demand is there but the planes are at capacity it is easier to plan in an extra flight than to find a plane which is much bigger. I have seen it between London and several European airports.

Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58195/different-airlines-same-destination-leave-about-the-same-time-why

They are two different flights, QR4788 is operated by IndiGo (codeshare), you can also find the same flight under IndiGo with flight number 1322. QR528 is operated by Qatar Airways.

Seems surprising that they aren't required to disclose that it's operated by a different carrier on the booking screen in case of a code share like that. At least for flights to or from the U.S., as far as I know, this is required. I would have assumed that the EU would have a similar regulation.

That's a skyscanner search screenshot and not the booking screen of the airline.
